# Ubuntu - Microphone Sensibility Disable AutoAdjusting

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

My microphone when I'm on call at google meet, simply automatically raises the sensitivity as I speak, I would like to disable this automatic adjustment. It gets in the way and sometimes you can hear a needle falling on the floor.

I have already installed Pulse Audio to see if I can control it definitively, but without success.

I'm using:

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu

DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04

DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj1Wn.png)